# confusion in a linear algebra theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

[Insights about $Tv_j=w_j$, the linear maps and basis of domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272797/insights-about-tv-j-w-j-the-linear-maps-and-basis-of-domain)

I have a question about the theorem mentioned in the link above. I understand what the theorem is saying, but a little uncertain. it states that the linear map is unique if given a set of basis, but I think there is a counter-example.

Suppose 1 is a basis in a polynomial vector space, then D(1) = 0, D^2(1) = 0, where D is the differential operator. But D and D^2 are not the same linear map, therefore the linear map is not unique.

Can anyone tell me if I misinterpret the theorem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Suppose that $1$ is a basis in a polynomial vector space"*.  That would necessarily mean that the vector space you're looking at is the space of *constant functions*.

What is it that the differential operator does on the space of constant functions?  It maps everything to zero.  In that sense, I would say that $D$ and $D^2$ are indeed the same map *over the space of constant functions*.

If there is any one thing that you have misunderstood, I would say it's the definition of a "basis".

Comment: To make it clear, if I choose another basis (1,x,x^2) with the same differential operator, then the unique part is still true since x and x^2 are mapped into different values, despite that the constant term is mapped into 0 by both operators?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to put it. I'd say that rather than "choosing a new basis", you're "choosing a new space".